# reactjs node modules form dynamic children

Tags: forms, dynamic, reactjs, listeners

I have a dynamic form:

```
var Form =  React.createClass({
    log:  function(e) {
      console.log(e.target.value);
    },

    getInitialState: function () {
     return {counter: 2};
    },

    handleChange : function(e) {
      this.setState({counter: parseInt(e.target.value)});
    },

    render: function () {
      var fields = [
        React.createElement('input', {key: -2, onChange: this.handleChange}),
        React.createElement('input', {key: -1, onChange: this.log})
      ];

      for (var x = 0; x < this.state.counter; x++) {
        fields.push(React.createElement('input', {key: x, onChange: this.log}));
      }

      return React.createElement('div', {}, fields);
    }
  });
```

The form is in a separate node module and I require it as:

```
 var Form  = require('custom-forms');
```

In the first input field I control the number of input fields. The log method of the newly created input fields is never invoked. There are no listeners for the new input fields.

When I move the form in the main project, everything is ok. The values are logged on the console when there is a change in the input.

Does anyone know where the problem could come from?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? If the `Form` component is not being loaded, try requiring it with its relative path, e.g. `var Form = require('./custom-forms.jsx')`. Can you post your code that shows how you use your `Form` component?

Comment: The form is loaded, I see the input fileds but there are no listeners.